# starting Standalone LDAP Daemon, slapd

Tags: linux, redhat, ldap, openldap

I am following [THIS](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html) guide to install an ldap server. At step 9 i use:

```
/usr/local/libexec/slapd
```

instead of:

```
su root -c /usr/local/libexec/slapd
```

since i dont have access to su

I get this message:

```
/usr/local/libexec/slapd: error while loading shared libraries: libdb-6.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when i try: `ldd /usr/local/libexec/slapd`

I Get:

```
/usr/local/libexec/slapd linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fffe01ff000)
libdb-5.3.so => /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.6.0/lib/libdb-6.0.so (0x00007fe2f743e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003fd1400000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000003fd2c00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003fd0c00000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000                                                                fe2f743e000) 
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003fd1400000) libr                                                                                                                                                             
esolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000003fd2c00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/lib
```

Can anyone see a problem with this?

Comment: What's wrong with the `openldap-servers` package?

Comment: I don't know, is that an alternative to what I am trying?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the `/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.6.0/lib/libdb-6.0.so` file exists and is readable by your account. If that is the case, try setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to include that directory:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.6.0/lib
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then try running the `slapd` executable again.

Comment: the file exists and is readable. i get same error, but when i run `$ ldd /usr/local/libexec/slapd` it says: `/usr/local/libexec/slapd: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.6.0/lib/libdb-6.0.so: invalid ELF header`

Comment: Then there appears to be a problem with your local Berkeley DB installation.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you *must* step outside the package manager just install the appropriate package for your distribution. For RHEL and kin that package is `openldap-servers`. In general, if you're  compiling from source (outside your package manager), you're doing it wrong.